# Getting an error "mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host"

Tags: python, sql, database

So I'm trying to establish a connection to an SQL database through python. My code is right, but when I run it,I get the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host.
```

I have tried to see how I can fix it, but this is the error the persists. If someone can help, it would be great.

**Update:**
Following code added from user’s comment:

```
import mysql.connector 

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="myusername", password="mypassword" ) 
print(mydb)
```

Comment: Please update the question with the associated code.  The error suggests the hostname / IP address of the server is wrong.  (But difficult to say for sure without seeing the code.) Thanks.

Comment: import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="myusername",
  password="mypassword"
)

print(mydb)

Comment: Is the server (background task) running?

Comment: Im trying to establish a connection to the server remotely so I'm not sure if it is running or not

Comment: Verify if the MySQL server (task) is running on the remote server.  If not, that’s why you can’t connect to it; so it needs to be started.  Then, try the connection again.

Comment: `localhost` refers to the machine that is currently running the code (that is, *your machine*) and can never refer to a remote server. You need to set `host` to the ip address of the server, e.g. `www.demo.com` or `255.255.0.0` The name *local* in *localhost* should be a hint.

Comment: @booboo - YES.  Wow, can’t believe I missed that.  Nerrr.  Thank you.  (smh)

Comment: So I have to put my IP address into the local host spot?

Comment: @NeemaPatel - Use the **server’s** IP address in the `host` parameter.